# Integer vs int types, which is better?

Tags: java

Why does Java have these `Integer`, `Character` types and classes
while they are also adapting C's `int`, `char` etc
Sometimes when people are creating arrays, they tend to
use `Integer[] i = {......}`
rather than `int[] i = {....};`
what is the difference then?

Comment: Put the question title in Google. There will be a plenty of answers on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer` is an object, while `int` is a primitive. Whenever we pass an `int` into a function, we pass it as-is.

`Integer` wraps an int. In its case it is immutable so editing it via reference isn't going to work, but it *can* be put into generics. This can be set to null while `int` does not have a possibility of anything beyond `0` or a special value you interpret as a null condition, such as `-1` or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

For instance, `ArrayList<int>` is completely invalid while `ArrayList<Integer>` must be used with ints being wrapped.

With [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), however, we can immediately add an `int` to an ArrayList without manually wrapping it, and if we need a primitive when we `get()` the entry, it'll automatically unwrap it transparently.

In the end if you're doing calculations with a limited number of distinct variables or a fixed array, you should generally use `int`. When dealing with sets, lists, or maps, you should declare the collection as `FooCollection<Integer>` then `add(` an int directly allowing for autoboxing.

Answer (score 0):

In java,

- `Integer` is a wrapper class i.e. it is an `object` while `int` is a primitive.
- `Integer` default value is `null` while for int it is `0`
- There is a concept of autoboxing and auto-unboxing for these two types.
- An integer can be converted to an `int` and vice versa

Followign program demonstrates this

```
public class TestClass {

    int num;
    Integer number;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        System.out.println(testClass.num);
        System.out.println(testClass.number);
        testClass.autoBoxInt(testClass.num);

    }

    public void autoBoxInt(Integer number){
        System.out.println(number);     
    }
}
```

The output is

```
0
null
0
```

The statement `System.out.println(testCkass,num)` prints `int` default value i.e. `0`. `System.out.println(testClass.number)` prints `Integer` default value i.e. `null`. When you pass `testClass.num` to a method with parameter `Integer`, `int` is automatically converted into and `Integer` object. so the method prints out `0`.

The java collections framework uses autoboxing to convert primitives into Wrapper classes because they cannot take primitive values. They help fast retrieval and storing of objects into collections using hashing and hashcodes. Following example demonstrates this

```
Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
numbers.add(new Integer(10));
numbers.add(new Integer(4));
numbers.add(6);
numbers.add(-9);
numbers.add(new Integer(65));
System.out.println(numbers);
```

This prints out the set

```
[4, 65, 6, -9, 10]
```

To know what hashing is and how hashcodes are used, you can look these links
http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/27/what-are-hashcodes/
http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/26/what-is-the-significance-of-equals-method-in-java/

Comment: Your example should also include how autoboxing is used to put primitives into generic classes such as collections and then retrieve them quickly.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer`, `Character` and others like this are `Objects` while `int`, `char` and others like this are primitives.

The biggest difference is that an `Object` can be `null` while a primitive value can't.

It's recommended to use primitive values where you can because they use less memory.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference we can tell generally is Wrapper is objective representation of `primitive`.

[Wrapper classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) are used to represent primitive values when an `Object` is required.